# How to make buttons change colors using only JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseevent

I'm trying to make it when my mouse hovers over my buttons, it will change the color to black, and then when the mouse is off the button, it will change back to the same colors as before. I want my color change to be done in javascript instead of CSS, just because I'm trying to get an understanding of events and event handlers.

JS:

```
//Changing colors of operation colors 

//Multiply Color
const colorMultiply = document.getElementById('multiply')
colorMultiply.style.backgroundColor = "green" //Makes Color Green

//Divide Color
const colorDivide = document.getElementById('divide')
colorDivide.style.backgroundColor = "red"//Makes Color Red

//subtract color
const colorSubtract = document.getElementById('subtract')
colorSubtract.style.backgroundColor="blue"//Makes Color Blue

//add color
const colorAdd = document.getElementById('add')
colorAdd.style.backgroundColor="yellow"//Makes Color Yellow


//change font of numbers to blue (I did it like this incase anyone wants to color of a single number)
//Makes it easier for you to change a colour of one button
const number1 = document.getElementById('number1')
number1.style.color="blue"
const number2 = document.getElementById('number2')
number2.style.color="blue"
const number3 = document.getElementById('number3')
number3.style.color="blue"
const number4 = document.getElementById('number4')
number4.style.color="blue"
const number5 = document.getElementById('number5')
number5.style.color="blue"
const number6 = document.getElementById('number6')
number6.style.color="blue"
const number7 = document.getElementById('number7')
number7.style.color="blue"
const number8 = document.getElementById('number8')
number8.style.color="blue"
const number9 = document.getElementById('number9')
number9.style.color="blue"
const number0 = document.getElementById('number0')
number0.style.color="blue"
const decimal = document.getElementById('decimal')
decimal.style.color="blue"

//Changing color of the clear button
const clear = document.getElementById('clear')
clear.style.color="white"
clear.style.backgroundColor="black"

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Then we want to insert `memoryStoreButton` before the `clear` button:
var memoryStoreButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryStoreButton.innerHTML = "MS";
clear.before(memoryStoreButton); //puts button before clear

// Then we want the `memoryClearButton` before `memoryStoreButton`
var memoryClearButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryClearButton.innerHTML = "MC";
memoryStoreButton.before(memoryClearButton);//puts button before clear

// and finally, the `memoryRestoreButton` before `memoryClearButton`
var memoryRestoreButton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
memoryRestoreButton.innerHTML = "MR";
memoryClearButton.before(memoryRestoreButton);//puts button before clear

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//What number buttons are pressed
var numButton = document.querySelectorAll(".btn8");
var showNum = document.querySelector(".screen8");


numButton.forEach(function(button){
  button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    if(event.target.innerHTML == "C"){
      return showNum.value = "";
    } else if (event.target.innerHTML == "=") {
      return;
    }
    let view = event.target.dataset.num;
    showNum.value += view;
  });
});

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//When equal is pressed it calculates the numbers, and if no numbers were entered there will be a error mesage
var equalButton = document.querySelector("#equals")
equalButton.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if(showNum.value == ""){
    return alert("Please Enter a Value"); // If no numbers are being displayed, error alert.
  }
  showNum.value = showNum.value + "=" + eval(showNum.value);
});

//Align test to the right of screen
document.getElementById("numberBox").style.textAlign = "right";
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON").addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON").addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);

function mouseOver() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON").style.color = "black";
}

function mouseOut() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("BUTTON").style.color = "grey";
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

<title> Calculator 8 </title>
 <script src="fp.js" defer></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="fp.css">



</head>

<body>
 <section class="calculator8">
    <h1> Calculator 8 </h1>
  <form>
   <input type="text" name="calcScreeng" id="numberBox" class="screen8">
  </form>
  <div class="buttons8"> 
   <!-- operation buttons -->
   <button id="multiply" type="button" class="btn8 btn-mul" data-num="*">*</button>
   <button id="divide" type="button" class="btn8 btn-div" data-num="/">/</button>
   <button id="subtract" type="button" class="btn8 btn-sub" data-num="-">-</button>
   <button id="add" type="button" class="btn8 btn-add" data-num="+">+</button>
   <!-- number buttons -->
   <button id="decimal" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num=".">.</button>
   <button id="number9" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="9">9</button>
   <button id="number8" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="8">8</button>
   <button id="number7" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="7">7</button>
   <button id="number6" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="6">6</button>
   <button id="number5" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="5">5</button>
   <button id="number4" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="4">4</button>
   <button id="number3" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="3">3</button>
   <button id="number2" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="2">2</button>
   <button id="number1" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="1">1</button>
   <button id="number0" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey" data-num="0">0</button>
   <button id="equals" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">=</button>
   <button id="clear" type="button" class="btn8 btn-grey">C</button>


  </div>



 </section>


</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;

}

.calculator8{
 flex: 0 0 40%;
}
.screen8{
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 5rem;
 padding: 0.5rem;
 background: rgb(41,41,56);
 color: white;
 border:none;
}

.buttons8{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

button{
 flex:0 0 25%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 0.25rem 0;
 transition: all 2s ease;
}

.btn-kground: rgb(224,224,224);
}

.btn8{
 font-size: 4rem;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example

Comment: it's at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use JavaScript instead of CSS, you'll need to write event handlers for each button. One event handler will fire when a mouse is over the button ('mouseover'), the other event handler will fire when a mouse leaves the button ('mouseout').

This function will add event handlers to a single button:

```
function addButtonHandlers(btn) {

  // make gray button on mouseover
  btn.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
    btn.style.color = 'white';
  });

  // make white button on mouseout
  btn.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    btn.style.color = 'black';
  });
}
```

A working example:

```js
function addButtonHandlers(btn) {

  // make gray button on mouseover
  btn.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = 'gray';
    btn.style.color = 'white';
  });
  
  // make white buton on mouseout
  btn.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
    btn.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    btn.style.color = 'black';
  });
}

const testBtn = document.getElementById('testbtn');
addButtonHandlers(testBtn);
```

```css
button {
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<button id='testbtn'>Test Button</button>
```

Documentation on [mouse events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#Mouse_events) and [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the id of the button is calcButton, you would do this:

```
<html>
<body>
<button id = "calcButton"></button>
<style>
#calcButton {
    color: red;
}
#calcButton:hover {
    color: black;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Use that, but change the colours to what you want.

Comment: but I want it to be in my javascript like at the bottom of the code in the post?

Comment: cant help you then. don't know anything about js but the css code does exsactly the same thing as you want though.